# Queued job stuck, table possibly locked in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, queue

I am using queues to send email notifications in my Laravel application. I am using the database as a queue driver so there is a `jobs` DB table that looks something like:

```
id | queue | payload | attempts | reserved_at
```

I now have a bunch of unsent messages in the queue, but it's the first one that's causing all the trouble: it has `255` in the `attempts` column and when I try to delete the row in phpMyAdmin nothing happens - it hangs for about 30 seconds, then gives a blank screen.

After I restarted MySQL, it let me delete the row, and all the other messages sent correctly.

The content of the row (I looked closely in the `payload` field) is, on the surface, the same as all the other rows.

This is the job that is being executed:

```
public function handle()
{
    try {

        $this->order->sendOrderConfirmation();

    } catch( Exception $e ){

        Log::info('Unable to dispatch order confirmation email.', [
            'order'   => $this->order->id,
            'message' => $e->getMessage(),
            'code'    => $e->getCode(),
            'line'    => $e->getLine(),
            'file'    => $e->getFile()
        ]);

        $this->release();
    }
}
```

The log message above is nowhere to be found in the logs, but what I did find in the logs is this:

```
SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'attempts' at row 1 (SQL: update `jobs` set `reserved_at` = 1550737859, `attempts` = 256 where `id` = 1638) in /home/truvisi3/public_html/secure/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:647
```

It looks like it's trying to increment the attempts counter, but the field is limited to 255. Ok, but why is this breaking the whole queue and not just this process? And what can I do to stop this from happening in the future (besides manually changing the format of the attempts column to accept huge numbers)?

EDIT: here is the job class

```
class DispatchOrderConfirmationEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * @var Order
     */
    protected $order;
    public $tries = 10;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param Order $order
     */
    public function __construct(Order $order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        try {

            $this->order->sendOrderConfirmation();

        } catch( Exception $e ){

            $this->release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can define maximum number of attempts by adding: `$tries=254` to job class,

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the maximum number of attempts for a queued job, otherwise it will be tried indefinitely. When using the `database` driver this means the  number of attempts can exceed the maximum value for a MySQL `TINYINT UNSIGNED` field, causing a database exception to be thrown on the 256th attempt.

There are two ways to do this.

Using `--tries` when starting the worker process:

```sh
$ php artisan queue:work --tries=10
```

Or define a `$tries` property on your job class:

```php
public $tries = 10;
```

When both exist, the `$tries` property takes precedence.

It's a good idea to always specify a max attempts with your worker process using `--tries` so that queued listeners, mail, and anything else using your queues will eventually fail after too many attempts, and use the `$tries` property to override the limit when it makes sense for a specific job.

The reason your custom error message doesn't appear in your logs is because the `database` queue driver updates the `attempts` and `reserved_at` fields when it pops a job from the queue, and *then* sends the job to the worker class. Since incrementing `attempts` throws an uncaught database exception before the worker runs, your code is never called.

Comment: Last week I accepted this answer, however the problem has now reoccurred even with `$tries = 10` in my job class. Please advise.

Comment: @jovan Can you include the code for the job class and the stack trace? Remember if you use the `$tries` property that it only applies to that specific class - any other queued actions will have their own max attempts, including queued listeners or mail

Comment: I've added the job class to the question. As for the stack trace, there is no error logged by the attempt to send an email. There are only errors after 255 attempts that I mentioned. I can try logging something in the try/catch loop to see if we get anywhere the next time the problem occurs.

Comment: @jovan I just want to see the error to double check that the attempted job is actually the same class

Comment: There's only one job and one type of notification in the system (the order confirmation above).

Comment: @jovan is it possible that the record causing the problem existed in the database from before you added the max attempts property? After adding an attempt limit you would still need to fix those records, otherwise they will throw the same error (even with the attempt limit)

Comment: No, it's a new record.

Comment: @jovan what version of Laravel is this?

Comment: It's 5.4. I've tried restarting the queue also but no improvement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189453/discussion-between-travis-britz-and-jovan).