# Database is locked when queue runs in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-9

When I trying to run following commands:

```
php artisan queue:retry all
php artisan queue:work
```

Sometimes data entered in `jobs` and `failed_jobs` table. But, sometimes I got following error log:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 5 database is locked (SQL: update
> "jobs" set "reserved_at" = 1690175898, "attempts" = 1 where "id" =
> 1000) {"exception":"[object]
> (Illuminate\Database\QueryException(code: HY000): SQLSTATE[HY000]:
> General error: 5 database is locked (SQL: update "jobs" set
> "reserved_at" = 1690175898, "attempts" = 1 where "id" = 1000) at
> vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:716)
> [stacktrace]
> #0 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(676):
> Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback()
> #1 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(533):
> Illuminate\Database\Connection->run()
> #2 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(466):
> Illuminate\Database\Connection->affectingStatement()
> #3 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php(3205):
> Illuminate\Database\Connection->update()
> #4 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\DatabaseQueue.php(326):
> Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->update()
> #5 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\DatabaseQueue.php(309):
> Illuminate\Queue\DatabaseQueue->markJobAsReserved()
> #6 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\DatabaseQueue.php(221):
> Illuminate\Queue\DatabaseQueue->marshalJob()
> #7 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Concerns\ManagesTransactions.php(29):
> Illuminate\Queue\DatabaseQueue->Illuminate\Queue\{closure}()
> #8 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\DatabaseQueue.php(223):
> Illuminate\Database\Connection->transaction()
> #9 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php(345):
> Illuminate\Queue\DatabaseQueue->pop()
> #10 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php(354):
> Illuminate\Queue\Worker->Illuminate\Queue\{closure}()
> #11 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php(159):
> Illuminate\Queue\Worker->getNextJob()
> #12 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand.php(126):
> Illuminate\Queue\Worker->daemon()
> #13 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand.php(110):
> Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker()
> #14 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(36):
> Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->handle()
> #15 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Util.php(41):
> Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
> #16 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(93):
> Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure()
> #17 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(37):
> Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
> #18 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(653):
> Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call()
> #19 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(136):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->call()
> #20 vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php(291): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute()
> #21 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(121):
> Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
> #22 vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(989): Illuminate\Console\Command->run()
> #23 vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(299): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
> #24 vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(171): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
> #25 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Application.php(102):
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
> #26 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(129):
> Illuminate\Console\Application->run()
> #27 artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle()
> #28 {main}

Laravel: 9.2

Database: sqlite

Comment: As I know `SQLite` doesn't handle concurrency like other databases (MySQL / PostgreSQL)

Comment: add your job code if possible?

Answer (score -1):

Set a maximum number of attempts for queued jobs to avoid indefinite retries. In the case of the database driver, exceeding the limit for a MySQL TINYINT UNSIGNED field (256 attempts) can lead to a database exception.

To set maximum number of tries:

```
php artisan queue:work --tries=10
```

See more on this in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54817042/15338342).

Comment: This is not correct - the question is asking about a sqlite database, not MySQL.